# Loopback 4 binding USER_SERVICE with a custom user service

Tags: binding, bind, loopbackjs, loopback4

I am trying to use my custom `MyUserService` which implement `UserService<MyUser, MyCredentials>`:

```
export class MyUserService implements UserService<Account, LoginCredential> { ... }
```

The difference from loopback's `User`, and `Credentials` are:

- `MyUser.id` is a `number` (while loopback's `User.id` is a `string`)
- `MyCredentials` has properties: `identity` and `secret` (while loopback's `Credentials` has properties: `email` and `secret`)
- `MyUser.credential` is the relationship (instead of loopback's `User.userCredentials`)

The issue is, when I am trying to bind (in `application.ts`) with:

```
this.bind(UserServiceBindings.USER_SERVICE).toClass(MyUserService);
```

it would not work due to:

```
Argument of type 'typeof MyUserService' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Constructor<UserService<User, Credentials>>'.
  Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'new (myUserRepository: MyUserRepository, passwordHasher: PasswordHasher<string>) => MyUserService' is not assignable to type 'new (...args: any[]) => UserService<User, Credentials>'.
      Construct signature return types 'MyUserService' and 'UserService<User, Credentials>' are incompatible.
        The types of 'verifyCredentials' are incompatible between these types.
          Type '(myCredentials: MyCredentials) => Promise<MyUser>' is not assignable to type '(credentials: Credentials) => Promise<User>'.
            Types of parameters 'myCredentials' and 'credentials' are incompatible.
              Property 'identity' is missing in type 'Credentials' but required in type 'MyCredentials'.ts(2345)
myuser.repository.ts(8, 3): 'identity' is declared here.
```

In other words, it does not let me bind my **custom** UserService, unless I follow these rules:

- the property of the credential in user has to be exactly `userCredentials`
- the credential has to have an `email` and `password` property
- the user's ID has to be in a `string` type
- ...etc (probably missed much more constraints)

My question is:

How can I bind my custom user service, where I can customize what data is stored in the `credentials`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was more simple than I thought. Long story short:

Simply make sure that I am importing **my own UserServiceBindings** and not Loopback's default `UserServiceBindings`.

---

In my case, my `UserServiceBindings` in  `application.ts` was the following:

```
import {UserServiceBindings} from '@loopback/authentication-jwt';
```

which imports the Loopback's default `UserServiceBindings`, which cause the issue. By replacing the import with a new import to mine `UserServiceBindings`:

```
import {UserServiceBindings} from './mybindings';
```

have solved the issue.